# Use Simultaneously Equation Simplification and a Particular Method in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am working with a very large system of non-linear, 1st order coupled ODEs which seem to be stiff. I have been trying to solve them via `NDSolve` with several methods, finding `StiffnessSwitching` to be the one that best fits my problem. However, for certain values of the parameters, *Mathematica* complains about not being able to obtain an explicit expression for the ODEs. I have been able to solve this by switching the `Method` to `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"}`. However, when I do this, I cannot specify that I still want the numerical method to be `StiffnessSwitching`. I have tried to use `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve", "StiffnessSwitching"}`, but it doesn't work. How can I use these two methods (or, as I understand it, the method for solving the ODEs and the one that simplifies the expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set

```
Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
           "EquationSimplification" -> Solve}
```

BTW this is mentioned in **Details and Options** section of document of `NDSolve`/`NDSolveValue`, I admit this isn't immediately obvious, though.